# The semigroup of Laplace-Beltrami operator on 3-flat torus

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, fourier-transform, semigroups-of-operators

I am studying a recent paper in which the author worked on the rectangular, flat 3 tori. It can be realized, the author explained, as $\mathbb{R}^3 \over (L_1 \mathbb Z \times L_2 \mathbb Z \times L_3 \mathbb Z)$ with $L_j \in (0, \infty),j=1,2,3.$ For notational convenience, we use the coordinates for the standard torus $\mathbb{T}^3 :=
{\mathbb{R}^3 \over \mathbb{Z}^3}$ and incorporate the geometry of the torus into the Riemannian metric, using the corresponding Laplace-Beltrami operator

$$\triangle = \sum_{j=1}^3 L_j^{-2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2}$$

We then define the Schrodinger propagator $e^{i t \triangle} $ by

$$\mathcal{F}(e^{i t \triangle } f)(\xi)=e^{- 2 \pi i t \sum_{j=1}^3 L_j^{-2} \xi_j^2} \hat{f}(\xi), \,\,\, for\,\,\, \xi =(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)\in \mathbb{Z}^3.$$

I have some difficulties understanding how he scaled the coordinates of the Laplace operator. Also, I can not get how he got the semigroup. Could you please explain for me in details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the scaling in the paper is as given, it is wrong. The factors should be $L_j^{-2}$ instead of $L_j^{-1}$. (This is a fairly innocent typo that probably doesn't effect the main result at all.)

Comment: I also don't know what you mean by "how he got the semigroup": the formula for $e^{it\triangle}$ is almost a definition. You may wish to edit your question to clarify what it is that you want to know.

Comment: @WillieWong It was my typo, and I edited it. My question is, what is the motivation that made him consider such a definition?

Comment: Which definition? The Schroedinger propagator's definition is standard. Given arbitrary $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^3)$, you have that $e^{it\triangle}f$ solves the Schroedinger equation $i \partial_t \phi + \triangle \phi = 0$ with initial data $f$. (Its formula comes from taking the spatial Fourier transform of the equation, which due to the separability becomes a system of decoupled ODEs.)

Comment: @WillieWong I am confused with the Laplacian with these weights! is it compensating the weights in the tori? How can I show this relation if I am right?

Comment: In general, if the Riemannian metric scales by a factor of $h$, the Laplace-Beltrami operator scales by a factor of $h^{-2}$. And the Laplace-Beltrami operator on a product space (with the product metric) is the sum of the operators on the base spaces. So in this case, regard the torus as the product of three circles, each scaled by $L_i$. The Laplace-Beltrami operator on the torus is the sum of the scaled Laplace operators on the circles, ie $\sum_i L_i^{-2}\partial_i^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just overthinking it since this is basically just a multivariable calculus change of variables.

The transformation $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \mapsto (y_1,y_2,y_3) = (L_1 x_1, L_2, x_2, L_3 x_3)$$
maps the torus $\mathbb{T}^3 = \mathbb{R}^3 / \mathbb{Z}^3$ to the rectangular torus $\mathbb{R}^3 / L_1\mathbb{Z} \times L_2 \mathbb{Z}\times L_3 \mathbb{Z}$. In other words, this defines a *change of variables* between the standard torus and the rectangular torus.

The change of variables satisfies
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = L_i \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$$

So the Laplace operator on the rectangular tori
$$ \sum \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\right)^2 = \sum \frac{1}{(L_i)^2} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \right)^2 $$
in the new coordinates.

Comment: Indeed. I were overthinking.